# css - align text below image in a span

Tags: html, css

I want to show text below image in these spans and spans do not jump to new line:

```
<span class="smileycode" id=":sm:">
    <img src="images/smiley/sm.png">:sm:
</span>&nbsp;
<span class="smileycode" id=":sq:">
    <img src="images/smiley/sq.png">:sq:
</span>&nbsp;
```

any suggestion?

Comment: What text are you trying to add below? Is that the :sm:, :sq: part?

Answer (score 6):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/udavoma/1/edit)

[image]

```
.smileycode{
  display:inline-block;
}
.smileycode img{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your class.

```
.smileycode
{
display:block;
}
```

This will convert you span into block level elements and shall make them jump to the next line.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

**EDIT**

If you want to make sure that the text appears like a caption just below the image, you can use `display:table-caption;` to achieve this.

Below is a working example.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tVsp9/)**

**The CSS:**

```
.smileycode{display:table-caption;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nathan is right. Alternatively, you could use a block level element instead of a span, such as a `div`

Comment: display:table-caption was very nice one

Comment: You can also add a `float:left` to `.smileycode` to get it next to each other. For instance, `.smileycode{display:table-caption; float:left;}` - @exim

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code. As you can see I've made a table with no borders that shows the images as you want.

```
<table id="yourid" border="0">
 <tr>
    <td width="50%">
        <span class="smileycode" id=":sm:"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ngS6rsb.png"></span>
        </td>
    <td width="50%"><span class="smileycode" id=":sq:"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ngS6rsb.png"></span>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
        :sm:
    </td>
    <td width="50%">:sq:
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Working example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHaee/)

Answer (score 1):

Just another way you *could* go about this problem... Taking advantage of `:after` and custom attributes.

**HTML w/ custom attrs**

```
<span class="smileycode" id=":sm:" data-text=":sm:">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </span>
<span class="smileycode" id=":sq:" data-text=":sq:">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
        <span class="smileycode" id=":sm:" data-text=":sm:">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </span>
<span class="smileycode" id=":sq:" data-text=":sq:">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
        <span class="smileycode" id=":sm:" data-text=":sm:">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </span>
<span class="smileycode" id=":sq:" data-text=":sq:">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</span>
```

**CSS w/ pseudo-elements**

```
.smileycode {
    position: relative;
}
.smileycode:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(data-text);
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/TUCkk/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is not that difficult. Effective usage of `<pre>` / `<br>` and then `display style` will do the trick for you . See the code below :

**HTML :**

```
    <body>

  <span class="smileycode" style="display:inline-table" id=":sm:">
    <img src="images/smiley/sm.png"><pre>:sm:</pre>
</span>&nbsp;

<span class="smileycode" style="display:inline-table" id=":sq:">
  <img src="images/smiley/sq.png"><pre>:sq:</pre>
</span>&nbsp;

</body>
```

See the working solution here : http://jsbin.com/AHiYuPO/2/edit . Remember to `run with js`.

Comment: do not want to use tables

Comment: You dont have to use tables if you don't want to. See my updated answer above @exim

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hcDne/

```
<div class="smileycode" id=":sm:"><img src="http://www.zeropages.com/smileys/sm_2828a.gif">:sm:</div>&nbsp;<div class="smileycode" id=":sq:"><img src="http://www.zeropages.com/smileys/sm_2828a.gif">:sq:</div>

.smileycode{
    width:30px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some `table` based approach here. Since I am more of a table-less person I offer a left-stacking solution using `float: left`.

You will have to wrap your existing span with one more span that float it to the left.

```
<span class="pull-left"><span class="smileycode" id=":sm:">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/dddddd/ffffff">:sm:
    </span></span>&nbsp;
<span class="pull-left"><span class="smileycode" id=":sq:">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/dddddd/ffffff">:sq:
    </span></span>&nbsp;
```

CSS:

```
span.smileycode img {
    display: block;
}
.pull-left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bND5Z/

Answer (score 0):

```
.smileycode {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.smileycode img {
    display: block;
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/92Dpb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on an [image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=v3of0x&s=5) you provided me, here is a complete solution.

Markup:

```
<div class="smileycode" id=":sm:">
    <span>:sm:</span>
    <img src="http://www.zeropages.com/smileys/sm_2828a.gif" />
</div>
<div class="smileycode" id=":sq:">
    <span>:sq:</span>
    <img src="http://www.zeropages.com/smileys/sm_2828a.gif" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.smileycode { clear:both; padding:5px; }
.smileycode span { float:left; padding:3px 0px 0 0; width:30px; }
.smileycode img { float:left; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Y8L/)

Answer (score 0):

As @Roko said but add a hack css for compatibility with old IEs :

```
 .smileycode {
   display:inline-block;
   *display: inline;
 }
```

Also I would add a

```
 text-align:center;
 line-height:1.2em;
```

to your span. But it's just design detail :) as other can have added in their examples !

Also you can clean all your `&nbsp;` of your HTML code (if you can)